# Always getting to the else part in the if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am having a problem getting this code to work. Whenever I input 249 or anything lower, it works as it should. But anything else gets me the `else` statement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ILAB02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double salesAmount, shippingAmount;
            salesAmount = 0.00;
            shippingAmount = 0.00;
            Console.WriteLine("What is the total amount of sales?");
            salesAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (salesAmount > 5000.00)
            {
                shippingAmount = 20.00;
            }
            if (salesAmount > 1000.00 && salesAmount <= 5000.00)
            {
                shippingAmount = 15.00;
            }
            if (salesAmount > 500.00 && salesAmount<=1000.00)
            {
                shippingAmount = 10.00;
            }
            if (salesAmount > 250.00 && salesAmount <=500.00)
            {
                shippingAmount = 8.00;
            }
            if (salesAmount > 0.00 && salesAmount <=250.00)
            {
                shippingAmount = 5.00;
            }
            else
            {
                shippingAmount = 0.00;
                Console.WriteLine("Error incorrect input!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total sales amount is {0:C}",salesAmount);
            Console.WriteLine("Shipping charges is {0:C}", shippingAmount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible title, no [mcve]. Read [ask].

Comment: As an aside, you should use `decimal` for monetary values.

Comment: Learn [how to use a debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and step through your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `else if`. Now your code will check the first `if`, if that's not true it goes straight to the `else` as it's supposed to do and the other conditions are never checked:

```
    if (salesAmount > 5000.00)
    {
        shippingAmount = 20.00;
    }
    else if (salesAmount > 1000.00 && salesAmount <= 5000.00)
    {
        shippingAmount = 15.00;
    }
    else if (salesAmount > 500.00 && salesAmount<=1000.00)
    {
        shippingAmount = 10.00;
    }
    else if (salesAmount > 250.00 && salesAmount <=500.00)
    {
        shippingAmount = 8.00;
    }
    else if (salesAmount > 0.00 && salesAmount <=250.00)
    {
        shippingAmount = 5.00;
    }
    else
    {
        shippingAmount = 0.00;
        Console.WriteLine("Error incorrect input!");
    }
```

Edit: little sidenode, your title should be about your problem. For example "if-condition not reached".

Comment: Also the second condition on the ifs is not needed.

Comment: In this case the else is needed. if any one of the `else if` conditions are true the final else will not be evaluated as a previous `else` evaluation was already true. Without the `else` each if statement is evaluated independently and the last, and only, one with an else will always decide the outcome.

Comment: Ah.  I missed the else if's.  Thanks guys!! I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple my friend, just change all the 'If's except from the first one to an 'ElseIf'